# Analytics API calls fail if they's run within an Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, azure-worker-roles

I can't get a Data.Ga.Get report request to work. It seems like there's something about being inside an Azure Worker Role that's incompatible with the Analytics API.

```
string mets = "ga:visits,ga:pageviews";

var reportRequest = service.Data.Ga.Get(creds.ProfileId,
                                        startDate.Year + "-" + startDate.Month.ToString("D2") + "-" + startDate.Day.ToString("D2"),
                                        endDate.Year + "-" + endDate.Month.ToString("D2") + "-" + endDate.Day.ToString("D2"),
                                        mets);
reportRequest.StartIndex = 1;
reportRequest.Dimensions = "ga:date,ga:pagePath";
reportRequest.MaxResults = 10000;
reportRequest.Sort = "ga:date";

GaData resp = reportRequest.Execute();
```

Every time I run the Execute method on the report request, it returns an ObjectDisposedException...
  {"Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.HttpListener'."}

If I try it from a direct Visual Studio debug session, it works fine, but as soon as I emulate the Azure Worker Role, I get the error.

I've raised the worker role to Elevated execution level.

I've tried adding some endpoints/ports but I can't find any documentation telling whether any additional ports are required.

I've put my client_secrets.json file in the Role alongside the .DLLs. I wonder if the API is looking somewhere else for that file.

It seems like a strange error (that it's not working with the HttpListener). I've even tried explicitly creating an HttpListener on port 8080 and that works fine without error.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which version of the client lib are you using? Where did you get it?

Comment: I'm using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 (1.8.0.82 using NuGet), and Windows Azure Tools 2.2.

Comment: I don't know Azure, and have no way of helping you test this. But this really sounds like it might be a bug in the client lib to me. I couldn't find it logged as an issue currently.  If you cant get it working it might be a good idea to log it as an issue. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list